# google bigquery SQL group by aggregate function

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, case-when

In big-query standard SQL I get the error message:

"Error: Column 7 contains an aggregation function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY at [17:22]

where column 7 is defined in the select clause as follows:-

CASE WHEN MIN(transaction_dttm) = transaction_dttm THEN 'NEW' ELSE 'EXISTING' END AS Fcquisition_Flag

Please note that transaction_date is a timestamp.

Any suggested solutions appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and show a simplified version of your query, along with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your `CASE` expression.  You should post the full query.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just want window function in a subquery:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (SELECT . . . ,
             (CASE WHEN transaction_dttm = MIN(transaction_dttm) OVER (PARTITION BY ?)
                   THEN 'NEW' ELSE 'EXISTING'
              END) AS Fcquisition_Flag
      FROM . . . 
     ) t
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

It is unclear what you want in the `PARTITION BY`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon & Tim.

Comment: The query I am trying to submit is as follows:

Comment: SELECT
 DATE(transaction_date) AS trans_date,
 TRIM(CONCAT(comp_quarter,' ',comp_year)) AS comp_year,
 CASE WHEN partners NOT IN ('Nok') THEN 'Not_Nok' ELSE 'Nok' END AS Partner_Flag,
 CASE WHEN MIN(transaction_date) = transaction_dttm THEN 'NEW' ELSE 'EXISTING' END AS Acquisition_Flag,
 COUNT (DISTINCT sids) AS No_Subs,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN se = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sp_count
FROM `mytable`
WHERE prod IN ('SSDPmed')
  AND DATE(transaction_dttm) = '2018-07-01'
  AND spf = 1
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4

Comment: this is the simplified query - without the CASE WHEN WHICH CREATES THE ACQUISITION FLAG it works fine.....but when I include it I get the error mentioned above